# Can you pass a variable to pandas.Series.str.extract?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I want to lookup for some values between the two. I am doing this with pd.Series.str.extract but it seems that I can't pass a compiled pattern to extract.

The first df loos like this:

```
In [91]: df.head()
Out[91]:

       text     lemma   pos  multiwordexpr   txp
0       ch'       che     c              0  CCHE
1  Politica  Politica   npt              0   SPN
2        l'        lo  rdms              0    RS
3        la        la  rdfs              0    RS
4    grandi    grande  a2mp              0    AP
```

The second df looks like this:

```
In [90]: mt.tail()
Out[90]: 

          form   lemma    morpho
505069   élite   élite  NOUN-F:p
505070   élite   élite  NOUN-F:s
505071  élites   élite  NOUN-F:p
505072  équipe  équipe  NOUN-F:p
505073  équipe  équipe  NOUN-F:s
```

Now, for txp='X', if text matches mt.form and lemma matches mt.lemma, then I want txp=mt.morpho.

I am trying to do the following (embedded in a function, so I can call it while iterating thorugh df):

```
word = re.compile(df.text[i])
lemma = re.compile(df.lemma[i])
mt.form.str.extract(word).dropna().index
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: This pattern contains no groups to capture.
```

Comment: You can't pass a regex object, what happens if you do `df.xcol.str.extract(x.text).dropna().index`?

Comment: @EdChum same exact error

Comment: It means that there are no matches, you have to post sample data, code your regex and the desired output

Comment: The same thing appens if I pass the value without brackets, like this: df.xcol.str.extract('fare').dropna().index but it works if I do df.xcol.str.extract('(fare)').dropna().index

Comment: If I pass the value manually it works, so it's not a problem of matching.

Comment: try `df.xcol.str.extract(r'fare').dropna().index`

Comment: @EdChum still nothing. I feel that the parenthesis sould be there, based on the doc here http://bit.ly/1KGVD5D. But I don't understand what the "group" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Ah I understand now, you need the parentheses to explicitly state the groups you wish to extract, there is a [cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) that shows this, are you really wanting to extract groups are you just looking for a contains style match? so `mt.form.str.contains(word).dropna().index`

Comment: @EdChum no groups, I am looking for an exact match. Pandas documentation says that match is deprecated. I tried to embed the brackets in re.compile like word = re.compile((df.text[i])) and also tried mt.form.str.contains((word)).dropna().index but none of them works